# How can I get MacOS and or Xcode to recognize my application as an image editor?

Tags: swift, macos

I am attempting to create an image editor (more like a pixel editor, but those are just details)

I started out with a basic application that I did not tag as a document based application because I am not creating any new formats

The encoding and decoding PNG data headache will come later, hopefully I can find a built in library that can turn PNG data into raw RGBA data and back later

What I need now is for my application to be considered an image application by the OS. When I try opening image files with my application, I get this message:

[image: Problem to solve]

> Pixel Draw cannot open files of the "PNG image" format

How can I modify the Xcode build settings or source code to tell Xcode or the OS that my app *can* and *should be able to* open PNG files?

Comment: Headache? Suggest [LodePNG](https://lodev.org/lodepng/).

Comment: That does not sound like a smart move unless you have a proper claim that you own that extension.  If you do, select a target and then set a document type under Info.

Comment: There is no need. Just open the files and process them. You can worry about file extensions much later.

Comment: How do you open the file, from the app? Is the app document based?

Comment: @Willeke I right click a PNG file, Open With > Other... to get a window, then I find my application, greyed out, then I check all applications as opposed to recommended applications, then there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Finder 'Open With' work for my application (Xcode, OS X)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998203/how-to-make-finder-open-with-work-for-my-application-xcode-os-x)